# Disable indenting on org-babel restclient edits

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, restclient

Despite I am not a new Emacs user, my elisp is nearly not existent.

I want to present some REST API stuff with epresent and org babel restclient. This is working fine until I want to edit a source block (request) inline during the presentation.

You can reproduce this by using the following org structure

```
* Testitem
#+begin_src restclient

#Get URL:
GET https://www.bing.com

#+end_src
```

I tried to disable electric indent mode in my init.el to check if this is the reason, but no luck.

```
(electric-indent-local-mode -1)
```

If I call the edit function (I need to change an URL param, due to preceding requests within the presentation) and confirm the edit with **C-c '**, the code is indented by 2 spaces and the source snippet is not shown/working anymore in epresent hereafter. It changed to:

```
* Testitem
#+begin_src restclient

  #Get URL:
  GET https://www.bing.com

#+end_src
```

Which is then not shown anymore and thus also not executable within epresent.

Can anyone point me to the reason for the indentation of the restclient source block and how to disably this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Org mode indents code in src blocks by 2 spaces by default. To change this you can set `org-edit-src-content-indentation` to `0` for no indentation.

Alternatively changing `org-src-preserve-indentation` to `t` may also achieve what you want to do.

Some description of indentation behaviour is in [this part of the manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Editing-source-code.html).

Comment: ok thx - this fixed the indentation. But somehow there seems to be a screen updating issue. The command block is still disappearing after the edit. I need to press "g" to refresh. epresent uses org-edit-src from org. Standard edits update correctly.